# Can I trigger a Yongnuo 560 III off-camera flash from Yongnuo RF-603II triggers on two different bodies?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo

I have two Canon bodies, three flashes, and two RF-603II triggers. I am planning to set the Yongnuo YN-560III as an off-camera flash at an event. The Yongnuo 560 III has its built-in RF-603 receiver. I know that I can hook up one RF-603II trigger on my first body with another on-camera flash to trigger the Yongnuo 560 III remotely. But can I also use the second RF-603II trigger on my second body to trigger this Yongnuo YN-560III flash as well with same channel setting? Can I switch to take the photo with a different body but trigger the same off-camera flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the channel and group settings are selected the same way on all three pieces of equipment you should be able to use either camera/transceiver to trigger the receiver in the off camera YN-560 III.